# Get last 2 rows from group on database side

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to improve performance of linq query for PostgreSQL. There are two tables (Parcles, ParcelStates) with relation 1:n. I need to get last 2 ParcelStates for each Parcel. Looks simple, I have following code:

```
IQueryable<Parcel> parcels = _dbContext.Parcels
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
   .Take(100);
```

Then getting states:

```
var states = await parcels
    .GroupJoin(_dbContext.ParcelStates, ps => ps.Id, p => p.ParcelId, (ps, p) => new { ps, p })
    .SelectMany(x => x.p.DefaultIfEmpty().OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).Take(2), (x,c) => c)
    .ToListAsync();
```

It returns me 180 states, and it is ok. But there is performance issue, because it generates not perform SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM parcels AS x
    WHERE x.isdeleted = FALSE
    ORDER BY c DESC, c0 DESC
    LIMIT @__p_1 OFFSET @__p_0
) AS t
LEFT JOIN parcelstates AS p ON t.id = p.parcelid
ORDER BY t.c DESC, t.c0 DESC, t.id
```

It takes all states from database, when I need only 2.

How to change LINQ to filter result on database side?

In logs I found:
 The LINQ expression 'Take(2)' could not be translated and will be evaluated

Comment: Client evaluation means you are using EF Core 1.x-2.x. The problem is EF Core, not your LINQ query. There is nothing you can do currently, wait for 3.0 release which presumably will process your query (w/o any modification) server side - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861792/group-and-select-first-from-two-tables-linq/57876672#57876672

Comment: thank you for help. please copy this comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insert the `SelectMany` expression into the `GroupJoin`, will it convert to SQL?

```
var states = await parcels
    .GroupJoin(_dbContext.ParcelStates, ps => ps.Id, p => p.ParcelId,
               (ps, p) => p.DefaultIfEmpty().OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).Take(2))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: @Chebur Did EF Core convert this to SQL properly?

Answer (score 1):

We can use a foreach loop which will translate to several very fast SQL lookups (should execute in < 1 second). Not ideal but I would still recommend writing a stored procedure to get this data, instead of relying on LINQ to SQL which doesn't always generate the most optimum query:

```
// Store a list of parcel states
var parcelStates = new List<ParcelState>();

// Read top 100 parcels from the database
var parcels = dbContext.Parcels
                       .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                       .Take(100);

// For each parcel, use SQL to lookup the 2 most recent parcel states
foreach (var p in parcels)
{
    var ps = dbContext.ParcelStates
                                .Where(ps => ps.ParcelId == p.Id)
                                .OrderByDescending(ps => ps.Id)
                                .Take(2);
    parcelStates.AddRange(ps);
}

// Now we have all parcel states for those parcels
Console.WriteLine($"Found {parcelStates.Count} parcel states for {parcels.Count} parcels");
```

Comment: It returns 0 items. p.ParcelStates is empty. Should I add `include`?

Comment: Please try // Read top 100 parcels from the database
var parcels = dbContext.Parcels.Include("ParcelState")
                       .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                       .Take(100);

Comment: works, but take the same time becaue generates the same query

Comment: Please see my edit, using dbContext.ParcelStates.Where()

Comment: Now it generates many queries but still slow, about 35 seconds for 180 rows. each query takes ~397.6ms

Comment: The queries should be instant, only returning 2 rows each. Do you have an index on the ParcelState.ParcelId column? That would improve the performance a lot.

Comment: Yes, I have an index

Comment: Either write a stored procedure, or make sure your code is running side-by-side the SQL server in the same rack so there is no latency for those queries.